# React component props with hyphen naming

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component Button in react with below interface

```
interface ButtonI extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  background?: string;
  border?: string;
  children?: React.ReactElement;
  className?: string;
  color?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  onClick?: (evt: any) => void;
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large' ;
}
```

I want to pass `data-test` as a prop, but I get error from typescript if I define `data-test` in interface as

```
data-test?:string;
```

Can someone tell me how can I pass props in react with hyphen in names?

Comment: Why cant you simply rename it?

Comment: @YTG I can't because data-test is the prop used by testers to write the identifiers, which is used throughout the project and now for just one scenario I can't ask testers to rename data-test in the whole project.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution as below:
In the interface I used single quotes

```
'data-test'?: string;
```

and while destructuring I aliased it as

```
const {
      background,
      border,
      children,
      className,
      color,
      disabled,
      onClick,
      size,
      'data-test':dataTest
    } = props;
```